# Delete value of a cell once used by another cell

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to enter a value in a `cell("A1")` then that cell would multiply with the value of `A3`, and new value will replace `A3`. `A1` is cleared.

I have entered the following code but it only does the whole column, I want it to apply to the whole column and Rows from 20 `T2` all the way to `AP2` so 42

```
    Private Sub worksheet_change(ByVal target As Range)
      If target.Column = 20 And target.Value > 0 Then
        Dim val As Double
        val = target.Value
        target.Value = 0
        Cells(target.Row, target.Column - 1).Value = val + Cells(target.Row, target.Column - 1).Value
      End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Not the clearest question...is the value of A3 to change?

Comment: yes, It's to enter stock into an excel table, alowing an empty cell at all time, to enter the quantity of stock just recived.

Comment: I have run the programe and all it gives me is a message box of the value i have entered, It dose not multiply with "A3". i really appriciate your help, after all I'm just a bigginer at all this.

Comment: I've added an optional answer

Comment: Thanks for your help now I have to apply it to all the cells

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub worksheet_change(ByVal target As Range)
  If target.Address = "$A$1" And target.Value > 0 Then
    Dim val As Double
    val = target.Value
    Range("A1").Value = 0
    Cells(3, 1) = val * Cells(3, 1)
  End If
End Sub
```

added into the Sheet1 module:

[image]

Seems to test ok:

[image]

Comment: One more thing, How would i apply it to a hole row in my case "A1"to"T1" and "A3" to "T3"?

Comment: ...so if someone wants to change a value in C1 then C3 should change? Should be easy enough - we just need to play with `target.Address = "$A$1"` and also `Range("A1").Value = 0`. Try changing them to `target.row = 1` and also `target.Value = 0` respectively ... ?

Comment: Hello again, I still have a problem with getting the program to run as I would like it to, I have managed to get the hole column to work but i need all 12 rows to work the rows stars at 20 so "T2" and skip a column next one is 22 so "V2"... all the way to "AP2"

Private Sub worksheet_change(ByVal target As Range)
  If target.Column = 20 And target.Value > 0 Then
  
    Dim val As Double
    val = target.Value
    target.Value = 0
    Cells(target.Row, target.Column - 1).Value = val + Cells(target.Row, target.Column - 1).Value
  End If

End Sub

Comment: @user3584495 rather than a comment, please add this as an edit to your original post - you can then format the code correctly and we will be more easily able to help

Comment: Sorry; I'm new to all this

Comment: @user3584495 no problem - should just makes it easier to read than your comment

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
Dim flagProgram As Boolean
Private Sub worksheet_change(ByVal target As Range)
Dim dblResult As Double
If flagProgram = False Then
    flagProgram = True
    dblResult = Cells(1, 1) * Cells(1, 3)
    Cells(1, 1) = ""
    flagProgram = False
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this.

```
Private Sub worksheet_change(ByVal target As Range)

  Dim rng As Range
  Dim db As Double
  Set target = Range("a1")
  If target.Value > 0 Then
    db = target.Value * Cells(1, 3)
    MsgBox db
    target.Value = ""
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: why the use of `msgBox` - just complicates things